# Can we access the key attribute when handling an event from a foreach template

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
// TEMPLATE    

<template for:each={itemList} for:item="item">
  <li key={item} onclick={handleItemClicked}>{item}</li>
</template>

// JS

itemList = ['A','B','C'];
selectedItem = '';

handleItemClicked(event) {
  this.selectedItem = event.target.key;
}
```

Is there a way to get to the key value ?

Comment: have you find how to get value from the key attribute?

Comment: I didn't. Most likely not possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set a data attribute on the element and read that.

Your template will look something like this:

```
<template for:each={itemList} for:item="item">
  <li key={item} data-item={item} onclick={handleItemClicked}>{item}</li>
</template>
```

And then your function will look like this:

```
handleItemClicked(event) {
        this.selectedItem = event.target.dataset.item;
    }
```

Also there are a few things wrong with your code other than this.

`onclick={handlItemClicked}` should be `onclick={handleItemClicked}`

`itemList = {'A','B','C'};` is not valid javascript. Assuming you want an array, it should be `itemList = ['A','B','C'];`

Comment: The code in the actual org was correct. That will teach me not to copy paste the code and write it just like that.
I did eventually write it like you proposed so if there's no way to access that key value I will mark it as best answer.

Comment: Interesting that I had to use `event.currentTarget` for `li.onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in sandbox :
HTML:

```
<template for:each={itemList} for:item="item">
  <li key={item} data-item={item} onclick={handleItemClicked}>{item}</li>
</template>
```

JS:

```
handleItemClicked(event) {
        this.selectedItem = event.currentTarget.dataset.item;
    }
```